# How do I center an element horizontally and position other elements relative to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a search bar in a React application (using material-ui v4). I have a TextField which I always want to be centered horizontally no matter what I put to the left or right of it.

Essentially I want to position everything else relative to the TextField and have it "anchored" in the middle.

I thought this would be simple in CSS but I can't crack it!

I can get the TextField centering on its own no problem with Grid Layout but can't get the button to position relative to it.

This is what I have so far. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious!

[image: Edit anchor-center-element]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  actionBarRootStyle: {
    display: "grid",
    justifyItems: "center",
    padding: 20
  },
  textFieldRootStyle: {
    border: "1px solid red"
  },
  buttonRootStyle: {
    //?????
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
    <Paper
      square={true}
      classes={{
        root: styles.actionBarRootStyle
      }}
    >
         {/* How do I position this button relative to the TextField so the TextField always stays centered ?*/}
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        classes={{
          root: styles.buttonRootStyle
        }}
      >
        Button to the Left
      </Button>

      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        classes={{
          root: styles.textFieldRootStyle
        }}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Comment: In order to position elements relative to `TextField`, they have to be its children.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 - Tried your suggestions. See CodeSandbox here. https://codesandbox.io/s/anchor-center-element-2-ojyhi?file=/src/App.js. Works ok for one or two buttons but the more you add the further to the left the set of buttons goes because their overall percentage is larger obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm following correctly, the textfield and button should be within the same container and if you make the container `position: relative` you can then make the button `position: absolute` and move its width to the left. Then you can just center the container to achieve the desired effect.

```css
:root {
  --TEXTFIELD_WIDTH: 300px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controls {
  position: relative;
}

.buttons-left {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.buttons-right {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(var(--TEXTFIELD_WIDTH));
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: var(--TEXTFIELD_WIDTH);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="buttons-left">
      <button>First</button>
      <button>Second</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-right">
      <button>Third</button>
      <button>Fourth</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the elements to be fixed widths though.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work if more buttons are added. The text field gets pushed to the right which is the original problem.

Comment: If you want to position a button to the left of the textfield without using a fixed width, you can instead position it using transform:  `transform: translateX(-100%);`

Comment: Yes I tried that here and it works fine for one button but if more get added the buttons move further and further to the left - https://codesandbox.io/s/anchor-center-element-2-ojyhi?file=/src/App.js. Try copying two more buttons below the existing one in my sandbox and see what happens.

Comment: If you want to add more buttons, just put all your buttons in their own container and position that container 100% of its width to the left of the textfield.

Comment: That is what I am doing in the updated link. Its what causes them to move to the left because 100% of a container with alot of buttons is pushing them further and further left.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear.  Are you saying you want your buttons to appear below each other, like a column of buttons, and that column should be to the left of the centered textfield?

Comment: My apologies. I want buttons to appear beside each other and up to two can be placed either side without influencing the centering of the TextField which should always be centered.

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer.  You just have to wrap your buttons in their own container and position the container instead of the individual buttons.  If you want to add more buttons to the right of the text field, just create another button or container of buttons with absolute positioning and place it to the right of the text field.